# Combinations of two letters from a $124$-element alphabet

Tags: combinatorics

The telephone company wants to add an area code composed of $2$ letters to every phone number. In order to do so, the company chose a special sign language containing $124$ different signs. If the company used $122$ of the signs fully and two remained unused, how many additional area codes can be created if the company uses all $124$ signs?

can this problem be solved using `permutation` or `combination` OR only application of number theory is needed ????

Comment: This is not about number theory, but purely combinatorics. I took the liberty to edit tag and title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: presumably order matters here as AB is different from BA. How many two letter combinations can be formed from $124$ how many from $122?$ Now subtract